# Parenthesis not being replaced in regex

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I know there are many ways over the internet but this case is a special one.

I need to replace `:)` with `<img src="smiley.gif">`. And

```
str.replace(/:)/g,'img src="smiley.gif"')
```

does not work! help me please!

Comment: In the future you can debug such problems by trying, for example, `':'.replace(/:/, 'test')`, and `')'.replace(/)/, 'test')`

Comment: yeah thanks. Just that I'm really really tired and my mind is just not in the right place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape the parenthesis:

```
str.replace(/:\)/g, '<img src="smiley.gif">');
```